# how to position left navigation icon

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, css-selectors

I'm trying to position my help icon to always at the bottom of the screen no matter the size of the user monitor screen but I'm struggling to make it work so I would be appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help.

Right now I've tried with margin and margin-top but it's not working when I change to different monitor size.

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height: 100%;">
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="left-nav">
      <a class="nav-logo" routerLink="/"></a>
      <span [style.marginTop.px]="8">{{title}}</span>

      <a class="left-nav-link" *ngFor="let nav of navList" [routerLink]="nav.path" routerLinkActive="active-nav-link">
        <div class="icon-wrap icons">
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons" src = {{nav.icon}}>
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons-hover" src = {{nav.iconHover}}>
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons-select" src = {{nav.iconSelect}}>
        </div>
        <div class="active-bar">
          <div class="active-bar-fill"></div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="help-nav-link" *ngFor="let nav of navHelp" [routerLink]="nav.path" routerLinkActive="active-nav-link">
        <div class="icon-wrap icons">
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons" src = {{nav.icon}}>
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons-hover" src = {{nav.iconHover}}>
          <img matTooltip = {{nav.name}} matTooltipPosition="right" matTooltipClass="tooltip" class = "nav-icons-select" src = {{nav.iconSelect}}>
        </div>
        <div class="active-bar">
          <div class="active-bar-fill"></div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```
mat-sidenav-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}

// This is for the top three icon

.left-nav-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 8px 0;
    min-height: 56px;
}

// This is for Help Icon
.help-nav-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 808px 0;
    min-height: 56px;
}
```

Different screen size

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please make [mre] not just one icon.

Comment: @Aase Have you tried absolute positioning? (Set the containers height to 100vh and make it's position relative)

Comment: @ikiK hi, I have updated my post. thanks

Comment: @Korgan I did  the absoulte positioning on help icon but still not working. I have updated my post so please can you take a look again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provide `position` instead of `margin`

```
.left-nav{
  position:relative;
}
.help-nav-link {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; /*can be changed as per your needs*/
 right: 0; /*can be changed as per your needs*/
}
```

Also, read about CSS Positions **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)**

Comment: Hi @richa_pnadey, thank you for providing me this. The help icon always stay at the bottom but it turn out it get very ugly when browser get smaller so do you know how I can make the help icon to just stay there instead of move up to the rest of icons. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you floating in not working then you try this in you style file.

```
         .left-nav{
position:relative;
```

}

```
.nav-logo{
position:absolute;
left:30%;
bottom:0%
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning and **relative** units, like `vh` should help.

This html code sample is close to your angular code in the question (I have removed useless details)

```html
<div style="height: 100vh;">
  <main>
    <div class="left-nav">

      <a class="left-nav-link">
        <div class="icon-wrap icons">
          <div class="icon"></div>    
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="help-nav-link">
        <div class="icon-wrap icons">
          <div class="icon"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="active-bar">
          <div class="active-bar-fill"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

```css
main {
    height: 100vh;
}
.left-nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width:3rem;
}
a.help-nav-link > div.icon-wrap {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
div.icon {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try angular material grid-lis?

https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

- This will help you to make your help icone bottem in every screen sizes!

As well as you can divide this to rows and columns

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_list_grid_view.asp

- As well as use like this to your code. It will fixed your problem

  ```
   position: relative;
   left:0 // change you own
   top:0// change you own
  ```